# How to show viewpager fragment position on action bar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I have nine fragments in viewpager. I want to show fragment position on action bar means if user working on fifth fragment then I want to show 5 on right corner of actionbar.  I am using below code but its showing only 1 but when user swipe and move to second fragment then its not showing 2. how can I achieve this or anyone can suggest me different idea ?

menu_fragment.xml -

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.prgguru.example.MainActivity" >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/fragmentPos"
            android:title=""
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>

</menu>
```

My addOnPageChangeListener below -

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                currentPage = position + 1;


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });




@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        //inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_item, menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.fragmentPos:
                 this.setTitle(currentPage);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want show viewpager fragment position on your action bar then edit below code to my bove ques and you successfully able to show page no.

Place Below line on your onPageScrolled -

```
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Below is onCreateOptionsMenu -

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        //inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_item, menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.fragmentPos);
        item.setTitle(String.valueOf(pos));

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```